# javascript IIFE sense (example analysis)

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm following [wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression#Establishing_private_variables_and_accessors):

```
var counter = (function(){
  var i = 0;

  return {
    get: function(){
      return i;
    },
    set: function( val ){
      i = val;
    },
    increment: function() {
      return ++i;
    }
  };
}());
```

I understand that there's a closure inside which holds the stack frame with the `i` variable and I can create multiple counters - that's clear. But why is IIFE syntax used here? If it rewrite the code without it, it works the same way:

```
var counter2 = function(){
  var i = 0;

  return {
    get: function(){
      return i;
    },
    set: function( val ){
      i = val;
    },
    increment: function() {
      return ++i;
    }
  };
};

c2 = counter2();
```

I'd appreciate an explanation on what is IIFE doing in wikipedia's example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you actually define a function.
In your variant the counter2 will still be in memory as the prototype for object c2.

Iffys are used when you only to create a single object of a certain type and not a prototype for later reuse.

Comment: I define a function, yes, so I may call it later on, whenever I want to. But what is the prototype for object c2? Can a function be a prototype?

Comment: By the way, can I say that IIFEs are used along with singletons?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz JavaScript is a prototype based language , not class based. Function is just another object actually, and when u create a new object with that function the object's prototype is the same as the function prototype ( in Firefox you can check this with c2.__proto__ === counter2.prototype  which will return true )

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz yeap ... at least from my knowledge (2nd question)

Comment: thanks fr the explanation. So a hash `{}` and an Array `[]` and a `function` are all objects and all have prototypes. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the function immediately lets it be anonymous. The gain is that you don't clutter the namespace with a function name you won't need afterwards.

There's no other difference, it might look like a detail, but why would would name this function if you don't reuse it ?

Comment: Then why creating a function at all if I don't reuse it? edit: I could just create an object...

Comment: Creating the function lets you define internal variables (`i` in your example) which aren't directly accessible and doesn't clutter the name space.

Comment: Hm, ok, so it's just about making the global scope as thin as possible, right?

Comment: It's also about privacy : you don't expose variables that shouldn't be changed from outside (this example isn't really good as there are a get and set function but you could imagine the same with just an increment and a get function). It's encapsulation.

Comment: Ok, I get it - so we provide public/private accessors this way. Thanks.